# Google Map Marker Clickable Area

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using this example: https://github.com/galex/android-mapviewballoons

My problem is that the clickable area is wider than the marker itself. For example, my Google Map marker is 25x25 then the clickable area would extend up to 70x70. This is a big problem for overlapping markers.[image]

When I clicked on the tip of that arrow, onTap is activated, even though the tap area is far from the marker.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: in HTML version I only see such issue with custom marker images, not with the default one

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaivior of `ItemizedOverlay`. 25x25 px is generally not an adquate touchable area for most human fingers.

You should override the `hitTest()` method if you want to modify the way an overlay item hit is tested.

Comment: Can you give example of hit test?

Answer (score -1):

For debugging :

Try using a [`TouchDelegate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html) for the View, you can specify the Touch rect for a give `View`

An example showing how to use the `TouchDelegate` :

```
public class TouchDelegateSample extends Activity { 
  Button mButton; 
  @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.touch_delegate_view); 
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delegated_button); 
    View parent = findViewById(R.id.touch_delegate_root); 
    // post a runnable to the parent view's message queue so its run 
after 
    // the view is drawn 
    parent.post(new Runnable() { 
      @Override 
      public void run() { 
        Rect delegateArea = new Rect(); 
        Button delegate = TouchDelegateSample.this.mButton; 
        delegate.getHitRect(delegateArea); 
        delegateArea.top -= 200; 
        TouchDelegate expandedArea = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, 
delegate); 
        // give the delegate to an ancestor of the view we're 
delegating the 
        // area to 
        if (View.class.isInstance(delegate.getParent())) { 
          ((View)delegate.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(expandedArea); 
        } 
      } 
    }); 
  } 
}
```

---

[`hitTest()`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#hitTest%28Item,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int,%20int%29)

> See if a given hit point is within the bounds of an item's marker. *Override to modify the way an item is hit tested*. The hit point is relative to the marker's bounds. The default implementation just checks to see if the hit point is within the touchable bounds of the marker.

Comment: For debugging can you call `View.getHitRect()`. I think it will be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. the marker is not a View, it's an overlayitem. Kindly check MyItemizedOverlay.java. Thanks.

Comment: `MyItemizedOverlayItem` extends `BalloonItemizedOverlay`, this is where you override [hitTest()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html)