# Clickable area for a default marker is larger than marker itself - Google Maps Android v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In my simple Android app with Google Maps API Android V2, I add display marker close to each other
But the click area of the marker is larger than the marker icon displayed, so when I click on one, the display info window of the other is shown !!

Did you already have this bug ?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm facing the same issue with my custom markers. These posts address the same issue. None of them has an accepted answer though.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048053/google-map-marker-clickable-area       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620537/android-if-markers-are-overlapping-each-other-on-the-map-then-the-click-event           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856677/customizing-clickable-area-on-a-marker-in-google-maps-v2-for-android

Comment: in HTML version I only see such issue with custom marker images